# Collapsed dropdown menus lost in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am upgrading to bootstrap 3, and have a simple dropdown menu in my nav (http://bootply.com/73584):

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- .navbar-toggle is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>

    <!-- Place everything within .nav-collapse to hide it until above 768px -->
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>



     </ul>

    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

In the collapsed mobile-view the dropdown still pops up; it doesn't add a submenu child as in Bootstrap 2. Is this missing or intentional? Anyone know how I could add the bootstrap 2 behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: For reference, the same also appears to apply to btn elements in nav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, and i don't know this is this missing or intentional (see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9253).

You could apply the Twitter's Bootstrap 2, style rules:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) 
{
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
    padding: 9px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777777;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .nav-collapse .btn {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu li + li a {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }

  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover,
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }

  .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
    background-color: #111111;
  }
  .nav-collapse.in .btn-group {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    display: none;
    float: none;
    max-width: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse .open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:before,
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu .divider {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before,
  .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    display: none;
  }
 }
```

See: http://bootply.com/73740 for the results.

Comment: This seems like a great potential answer, but applying this CSS has no affect for me.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @dave afaik this is already fixed in newer versions of BS, see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar (also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/9403)

Comment: I had no option to update Bootstrap so applying this between style tags worked perfectly.